# Xbox 360 de-friending someone

Tags: xbox-network

How would I go about doing this? I can't find anything useful in the Xbox 360's wonderfully informative menus.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this on the console, but I know that you can remove friends from [xbox.com](http://www.xbox.com). Log in using the Windows Live ID associated with your GamerTag, and go to the Friends Center. There is a "Remove" button by each person on your Friends List that you can use to remove them.

Comment: Nice, i accidently accepted a friend ages ago and when i'm streaming tv episodes from my mac, their name keeps popping up telling me they're online...i dont even know them!

Comment: Its also possible to suppress all log-in messages while you are watching a movie, this can be done through the system settings menu

Answer (score 9):

When you select a friend's gamertag and the menu pops up ("Invite to Party", etc.), one of the options near the bottom is "Remove Friend":

[image: Screenshot of Remove Friend option]

<sub>(Source: http://support.xbox.com/xbox-live/social/chat-managing-friends)</sub>